# Android: GIF not getting aligned at the center of the parent

Tags: android, gif

I have a GIF(using Movie and CustomView), which I am not able to align center of my parent RelativeLayout,  with following code:

```
public class GIFView extends View {

    private Movie mMovie;
    private long mMovieStart;

    int mGIFDrawable = R.raw.butterfly;

    public GIFView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);

        java.io.InputStream is;
        is = context.getResources().openRawResource(mGIFDrawable);
        mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
    }

    public GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrSet) {
        super(context, attrSet);
        setFocusable(true);

        java.io.InputStream is;
        is = context.getResources().openRawResource(mGIFDrawable);
        mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
    }

    public GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrSet, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrSet, defStyle);
        setFocusable(true);

        java.io.InputStream is;
        is = context.getResources().openRawResource(mGIFDrawable);
        mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(is);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        final long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        if (mMovieStart == 0) {
            mMovieStart = now;
        }
        final int relTime = (int) ((now - mMovieStart) % mMovie.duration());
        mMovie.setTime(relTime);
        mMovie.draw(canvas, 10, 10);
        this.invalidate();
    }
}
```

I am not able to align this view center of my parent RelativeLayout.
XML declaration is as follows:

```
<com.example.common.GIFView
        android:id="@+id/gif"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
```

Comment: please provide more detailed xml so we can help you

Comment: The parent of the GIF is the root layout with the usual property: android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: still not helpful sir, xml code will be a great help and also support it with a screenshot

Comment: Can you pls help me understand what does 10 in this line of code mean? mMovie.draw(canvas, 10, 10);. I think this is where GIF placement can be done. Becasue varying the val 10 to 100 or so varies GIF pos. However, when I tried setting 10, 10 to device width/2 and height/2, it still didn't go to the center(it just reached somewhere around).

Comment: Okay at first set `gravity` center

Comment: tried, still not working.

Comment: to get center you need to do (parentWidth / 2 - canvaswidth / 2)